# Matrix of all possible multipliable outcomes from two lists into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two lists and am trying to create a matrix of all possible multiplication outcomes in a `dataframe` using `pandas`.

***Lists:***

```
>>> L1
[8, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5]

>>> L2
[5, 3, 9, 1, 2, 6]
```

I have multiplied every item from `L1` with every item from `L2` as followed to formulate all possible outcomes:

```
>>> [[a*b] for a in L1 for b in L2]
[[40], [24], [72], [8], [16], [48], [5], [3], [9], [1], [2], [6], [20], [12], [36], [4], [8], [24], [10], [6], [18], [2], [4], [12], [35], [21], [63], [7], [14], [42], [25], [15], [45], [5], [10], [30]]
```

***Expected Output/Goal:***

***My goal is to now represent these values as a matrix using pandas*** but I am not sure of where to start. The first item in the lists are assigned the column/row name from `0-5`.

For example:

The `df` matrix should look something like:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  40  5 20 10 35 25
1  24  3 12  6 21 15
2  72  9 36 18 63 45
3  8   1  4  2  7 5
4  16  2  8  4 14 10
5  48  6 24 12 42 30
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could consider a solution with [`numpy.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
In [879]: pd.DataFrame(np.outer(L2, L1))
Out[879]: 
    0  1   2   3   4   5
0  40  5  20  10  35  25
1  24  3  12   6  21  15
2  72  9  36  18  63  45
3   8  1   4   2   7   5
4  16  2   8   4  14  10
5  48  6  24  12  42  30
```

---

#### Performance

Setup:

```
x = np.random.choice(26, 1000)
y = np.random.choice(26, 1000)

%timeit pd.DataFrame([[a*b for b in x] for a in y]) # Willem Van Onsem's solution          
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.outer(y, x)) # Proposed in this post
```

Results:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 566 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.75 ms per loop
```

The numpy solution is 150 times faster than a list comprehension.

Comment: Very elegant solution! ++

Comment: I said Thank You. I'm sorry if that implies something else to you... Regardless, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LearningToPython Glad to help. Good luck handling large lists with a list comprehension ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use *nested list comprehension*:

```
pd.DataFrame([[a*b for b in L1] for a in L2])
```

This generates:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([[a*b for b in L1] for a in L2])
    0  1   2   3   4   5
0  40  5  20  10  35  25
1  24  3  12   6  21  15
2  72  9  36  18  63  45
3   8  1   4   2   7   5
4  16  2   8   4  14  10
5  48  6  24  12  42  30
```

So the outer list comprehension `[... for a in L2]` iterates over `L2` and assigns the values to variable `a`. For every such variable, we generate a list (again with list comprehension) with `[a*b for b in L1]` where we thus iterate over the values in `L1` and generate a list where we multiply the values with `a`.

Comment: You make it look so easy! Thank You So Much ;)